# Access DB table and for every record in list create a new column in table

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

A list of POSUnitRecords is passed in. Im trying to access the table 'Records' in the db 'EPOSEntities'. Foreach POS I want to add another row in the 'Records' table.

```
public static void UpdateDataBase(List<POSUnitRecord> POSs)
        {
            EPOSEntities db = new EPOSEntities();
            var ent = from epos in db.Records
                      where epos.
                      //Columns in 'Records' table are 'Id' & 'Folder'

            foreach (POSUnitRecord pos in POSs)
            {
                //fields in pos are 'Id' & 'Folder'

            }
        }
```

////////////////////////////////

```
public class POSUnitRecord
{
    //[Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string FolderPath { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: What does `POSUnitRecord` class look like?

Comment: I get the `Foreach POS I want to add another row in the 'Records' table` part, but I'm not sure what you mean by `Im trying to access the table 'Records' in the db 'EPOSEntities'`, can you elaborate a bit?

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void UpdateDataBase(List<POSUnitRecord> POSs)
        {
            EPOSEntities db = new EPOSEntities();
            var ent = from epos in db.Records;
                      //where epos.
                      //Columns in 'Records' table are 'Id' & 'Folder'

            foreach (POSUnitRecord pos in POSs)
            {
                Record aRecord = new Record();
                aRecord.Id = pos.Id;
                aRecord.Folder = pos.FolderPath
                aRecord.New="put your value";
                ent.Add(aRecord);
            }            
    }
```